# Will the dextrorotatory and laevorotatory enantiomers always have a set of stereocenters with opposite absolute configuration?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

I was faced with a question where the skeletal structure of of D(+)-glucose was given and I was asked to give the right structure of L(-)glucose. I noticed that the correct answer was the one where all the stereocenters had opposite absolute configuration of those of D(+)glucose.

But my question is: Will the dextrorotatory and laevorotatory enantiomers always have a set of stereocenters with opposite absolute configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisely, these are based on the configurations proposed by German chemist Emil Fischer, who established the structures of many sugars.

> Emil Fischer elucidated these configurations for the aldohexoses in
>   1896. According to the Fischer convention, D sugars have the **same absolute configuration at the asymmetric center farthest removed from
>   their carbonyl group** as does D-glyceraldehyde. The L sugars, in
>   accordance with this convention, are mirror images of their D
>   counterparts,

[image]

Similary,the  Fischer projection for glucose  is shown below.

[image]

It is very important not to confuse these **enantiomers** with **epimers**   (two sugars that differ only in the configuration around one carbon atom e.g D-glucose and D-mannose, which differ only in
the stereochemistry at C-2)

[image]

References

- Voet and Voet Biochemistry
- Lehninnger Principles of Biochemistry
- Biochemistry (Campbell and Farrel)